# DIY LED controller

Tags: led, esp32, controller

I am building a LED controller using an ESP 32 and IRLB8721 mosfets. I have 3 RGB LEDs hooked in series. The whole thing is powered by a 12V power supply which says it is set into outputing only 350mA but I measured around 430mA using an other controller.

I do not know the LED type, I received this from a friend, measured the forward voltage of the LEDs tho, Green Vf=2.5V, Red Vf=1.68V Blue Vf=2,45V

My question is do I need any kind of resistors for the LEDS with this setup or will this circuit work as it is?

Here is the circuit diagram:
[image: circuit diagram]
And here is how the LEDs are wired:
[image: here is how the LEDs are wired]

So once again my question is do I need any kind of resistors for the LEDS with this setup or will this circuit work as it is?

**EDIT**: Added info about LEDs

Comment: LED data sheet needed.

Comment: @Andyaka I do not know the LED type, I received this from a friend, measured the forward voltage of the LEDs tho, Green Vf=2.5V,  Red Vf=1.68V Blue Vf=2,45V, I'll add this to the post

Comment: How do you know what the maximum allowable current is?

Comment: Tip: Draw your schematics with higher voltages at the top of the page so that current flows from top to bottom. Ground symbols should point downwards indicating "buried in the ground" rather than in the sky.

Comment: @Andyaka well I do not know, I don't know how to figure that out

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the tip, this was just a quick sketch

Comment: You can't figure it out - that's the point of the data sheet.

Comment: Simple answer is that unless you're driving LEDs with a constant current source you should ALWAYS use resistors.

Comment: @Andyaka well since I cannot figure that out, can I somehow measure that from the previous controller this setup used? That one is stuck in displaying pink that's why I am trying to build a new one

Comment: Where did you get the LEDs?

Comment: @Finbarr as I wrote above I got it from a friend who had this setup in a table but they lost the romote to the original controller and it's stuck in pink so I am trying to build a new controller

Comment: No you can't - get new LEDs that are supported by a data sheet. That is what an EE would do and presumably you are here to get knowledge from proper EE people?

Comment: @Andyaka well I was hoping I did't have to get new ones, my budges is kinda limited and shipping times are really bad

Comment: If all you want to do is play guesswork, start with a nice safe forward current like 20mA and concentrate on the controller.

Comment: @Finbarr thanks, do you think 1/4W resistors will be enough?

Comment: For the red ones, 12-(3*1.68) gives you 6.96V across the resistor, 0.02A through it gives you a resistance of 348 Ohms and 6.96*0.02 gives you a power dissipation of 139mW. So, yes.

Comment: @Finbarr thanks you are amazing :)

Comment: Are there exposed traces on the **bottoms** of these boards that you are taping down to a metal surface?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson nope, the whole bottom of the LED PCB is metal and it has thermal paste under it so the metal sheet can act as a heat sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the LED data sheet it’s hard to say for sure but you’re always better off with including a resistor and if the LEDs aren’t bright enough/turning on, lower the resistance from there. Do you know the power rating for the LEDs? If you do, you can calculate their rated current using their voltage drop and P=IV and from there figure out the required resistance you need. As far as your power supply goes, is it rated for or current limited to 350mA? If you are able to limit the current from your power supply then you won’t need a resistor. That being said if it’s only rated for 350mA don’t be driving it higher than that, you’ll burn out the power supply very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know nothing about the LEDs so I dont know the power of it. I can only guess, but that probably wont help, the PSU says it's output is 350 mA but when using the old controller when I was measuring the current going to the 3 leds I measured 430 mA with my multimeter so I do not know what's up with that

Comment: It sounds like the PSU is rated for 350 mA. Typically voltage supplies will give you a current rating, like in your case the 350 mA, that doesn't mean it will always output 350 mA and you can usually draw more current out of them like in your case 430 mA. You don't want to draw more than the 350 mA however or else you run the risk of damaging the supply. The output current is governed by the total resistance of your circuit I = V/R where your V is 12V. In this case I would definitely add in some additional resistance so that you're operating within it's limits.